Why the src of Image tag doesn't recognizes my jpg?
I'm trying to insert an image in my portfolio, but for some reason the tag  returns 404 and the Next Image returns the error The requested resource isn't a valid image for /myImage.jpg received text/html
this is the code block:
import Image from "next/image";
import { ReactElement } from "react";

const MyImage = ():ReactElement => {
    return (
        <Image
            fill
            src='/myImage.jpg'
            alt="MyImage"
            />
    )
}

export default MyImage


Image component is quite strict about handling image sources.
You are getting 404 which means not found  or invalid image.

Check you file location.


Make sure your myImage.jpg is placed correctly in public folder.


The requested resource isn't a valid image for /myImage.jpg received text/html


received text/html this error means you are passing html or the image might not be correctly served which can return an html error page. Please make sure the file actually exists at the path you are specifying and double check if that is a valid image.


If both option doesn't help.


Try to host the image online. If you want to use online image or url, you'll have to update next.config.js file to allow that domain for external images.

In your next.config.js:


module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'domainOfSiteYouHostedYourImage.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/**',
      },
    ],
  },
}



Hope this works and solves your problem
